# watch new field value and update the path value accordingly

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have two text fields. One is name field and another is path field. I want to change the path field value based on name field value.

**Path field**

```
<s-text-field
            ref="textFieldContentPath"
            v-model="objCn_mgmt.cntPath"
            maxlength="400"
          />
        </div>
```

**Name field**

```
<sui-text-field
        ref="textFieldJobName"
        v-model="objCn_mgmt.cntName"
        maxlength="400"
      />
```

**Script**

```
mounted() {
  this.objCn_mgmt.cntPath = 'some staic dta value' + objCn_mgmt.cntName
}
```

Now, it is kind of lookup. Path value will change based on name input.Can you suggest me better approach using computed or watchers for this?

Comment: Are s-text-field and sui-text-field different and custom components?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<sui-text-field
   ref="textFieldJobName"
   v-model="objCn_mgmt.cntName"
   maxlength="400"
   @input="cinput"
/>
```

and add `cinput()` into methods:

```
methods: {
    cinput(){
       this.objCn_mgmt.cntPath = 'some staic dta value' + this.objCn_mgmt.cntName
    },
  },
```